# Name of the Sci fi book where all human contact is via video link?

Tags: story-identification

I read this book as a child in the 70s. All I can remember is that all human contact is via video link. People have dinner parties where they have the same food and all their screens link as one (a bit like a video conferencing). Human reproduction is in vitro, there is no physical contact at all. So no concern about clothes or embarrassment regarding lack of clothes.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the world of Solaria, described in Asimov's "The Naked Sun". Did it have robots?

Comment: There was a short story involving humanity living in underground complexes ran by the machine, where it's incredibly rare anyone leaves their rooms, and understanding of how it all works has gone, some even worshipping the machine

Comment: @TomJNowell That would be The Machine Stops by E.M. Forrester. Amazingly, it was published in **1909**. Dude basically predicted the Internet :)

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224963/story-about-the-scientists-in-mars-that-are-less-cooperative-than-the-scientists (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 12):

This sounds pretty much as Asimov's [The Naked Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_Sun), but not all of it, as there is a slightly physical contact between the Solarians.

Comment: In The Naked Sun there was some very slight human interaction, but when Solaria was revisited in [Foundation and Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_and_Earth#Part_IV:_Solaria), the Solarians had moved to complete physical isolation. Maybe the OP is mixing the two books?

Answer (score 8):

It also sounds quite a bit like E.M. Forster's [The Machine Stops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machine_Stops), except that it's more of a short story than a book.

Comment: This sounds exactly like "The Machine Stops", it's even read in some Highschools as curriculum. I do remember it being a short story though. Only a few chapters, but one of the major themes was that there was no direct human interaction.